# RxJS: Treat first case specially, but continue streaming the rest

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming, observers

Say I wanted to separately handle the first event emitted by an Observable, but then continue my subscription.

For example, if I had the following chain:

```
observable.throttleTime(2000)
      .takeFirst(() => console.log('potato'))
      .switchMap((event:MouseEvent) => {
        const element:Element = event.target as Element;
        return this.innerObservable(('tomato'));
      })
      .subscribe(({result}) => console.log(result))
```

That fails, but how would I go about making such behaviour work?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do and RxJS does not have a [`takeFirst`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=takeFirst&type=) operator. If you are using [`switchMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap), its projection function is passed an `index` parameter. I'd suggest you use that to identify the first emitted value.

Answer (score 8):

Many RxJS 5 operators that take a callback function pass along also the index of the item going through. This means you could write for example the following:

```
observable.throttleTime(2000)
    .map((value, index) => index === 0 ? 'potato' : value)
    ...
    .subscribe(({result}) => console.log(result))
```

Indices are passed for example to `filter()`, `switchMap()`, `takeWhile()` operators and more.

Answer (score 2):

You can use two subscribers, one for the default case to be applied to all events and the other for the special case of the first event:

```js
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

//emit 4 values
const source = of(1, 2, 3, 4);

/*
Subscriber One - only first value: 1
Subscriber Two - all values: 1
Subscriber Two - all values: 2
Subscriber Two - all values: 3
Subscriber Two - all values: 4
*/
const subscriberOne = source
  .pipe(first())
  .subscribe((val) => console.log(`Subscriber One - only first value: ${val}`));
const subscriberTwo = source.subscribe((val) =>
  console.log(`Subscriber Two - all values: ${val}`)
);
```

see it live on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-paan19?file=index.ts)

And to answer your question, where there is a special handler for the first event and then a common handler for the rest of the event, excluding the first one:

```js
import { of, skip } from 'rxjs';
import { first, publish } from 'rxjs/operators';

// emit 4 values
const source = of(1, 2, 3, 4);
// hold until `others` until `connect()` is called, skip `source` first event
const others = publish()(source.pipe(skip(1)));
// marker to make sure first event handler ran before the others
let onceRan = false;

// general case, has to be declared before so `others.subscribe()`
// runs before `others.connect()` is called
const subscriberTwo = others.subscribe((val) =>
  console.log(`Subscriber Two - all values: ${val}, onceRan: ${onceRan}`)
);

// first event handler, `first()` => stops after the first event
const subscriberOne = source.pipe(first()).subscribe((val) => {
  console.log(`Subscriber One - only first value: ${val}, onceRan: ${onceRan}`);
  // toggle the merker
  onceRan = true;
  // release `others`
  others.connect();
});

/*
Output:
Subscriber One - only first value: 1, onceRan: false
Subscriber Two - all values: 2, onceRan: true
Subscriber Two - all values: 3, onceRan: true
Subscriber Two - all values: 4, onceRan: true
*/
```

see it live on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-w8ptke?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 1):

#### Simple solution to treat the first separately would be

```
let isFirstCame= false;

 observable
      .subscribe(({result}) =>
         if(!isFirst){
            //here is our first one
            doSpecialWithTheFirst(result);
            isFirstCame=true;
         }else{
           //All the remaining
           doOtherWithRemaining();
         })
```

Comment: I agree, using RxJs doesn't mean it is taboo to use if/else

Answer (score 0):

Use publish along with first and concat operators. Here is an example:

```
Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
 .publish(shared => {
    return  shared.first().mapTo('FIRST')
       .concat(shared.skip(1));
})
.subscribe(x=>console.log(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an operator that subscribes to the source observable, processes the first element and then removes itself from the chain. Let's call it `onFirst` because `takeFirst` is an existing operator in Java. Rxjs 5 example:

```
Observable.prototype.onFirst = function(callback) {
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    let source = this.publish()
    let subs = source.subscribe({
      next(v) {
        subs.unsubscribe()
        source.subscribe(observer)
        callback(v)
      },
      error(e) { observer.error(e) },
      complete() { observer.complete() }
    })
    source.connect()
  })
}

// This prints
// first: 1
// 2
// 3
Observable.of(1, 2, 3)
  .onFirst(v => console.log("first: " + v))
  .subscribe(console.log)
```